# Solve using Master Theorem $T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{4}) + n \log{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

$$T(n)=4T\left(\frac n4\right)+n\log n$$

Do I understand right that for me it is the case where $a=4$, $b=4$ and because $n^{\log4} > n\log n$ we get $T(n) \in\Theta(n^2)$ as a result?

Comment: Aren't you missing a $T(n)=$?

Comment: @Gary You are right! Edited

Comment: The critical exponent is $\log_4 4=1$.  Apply case 2 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form with $k=1$. You should get $T(n)=\Theta(n \log^2 n)$.